# Conditional formatting of the font in a WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid populated using a Dataset. I am trying to change the font colour of the data in two columns. I have it working using

```
REMOVED OLD CODE
```

But it isn't holding the colours very well especially when there is scrolling on the grid. It is also slow.

Is it possible to do this using an `IValueCoverter`  or is there some other more efficient way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have tried to take a new approach to this problem. I have created a class to return a bool and then use that bool to determine whether the font will be green or red.

CLASS

```
class EqualValuesColourConverter
{
    public static void ChangeColours(int pQty, int pPri, int pTot, int gQty, int gPri, int gTot)
    {
        int iqty = pQty;
        int gqty = gQty;
        int iprice = pPri;
        int gprice = gPri;
        int itotal = pTot;
        int gtotal = gTot;

        bool fontColor = true;

        if ((iqty == gqty) && (iprice == gprice) && (itotal == gtotal)) fontColor = true;
        else fontColor = false;

    }
 }
```

CALL TO CLASS

```
 string iqty = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Quantity"].ToString();
            string gqty = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Quantity"].ToString();
            string iprice = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Price"].ToString();
            string gprice = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Price"].ToString();
            string itotal = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Total"].ToString();
            string gtotal = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Total"].ToString();

            int pQty = int.Parse(iqty);
            int pPri = int.Parse(iprice);
            int pTot = int.Parse(itotal);
            int gQty = int.Parse(gqty);
            int gPri = int.Parse(gprice);
            int gTot = int.Parse(gtotal);

            EqualValuesColourConverter.ChangeColours(pQty, pPri, pTot, gQty, gPri, gTot);
```

XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="61" Header="Inv_Quantity" Binding="{Binding Inv_Quantity}">
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EqualValuesColourConverter}" Value="False" >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

I am trying to get it to work in two columns but it will only change the font colour in one.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = DgInvoiceLines.SelectedIndex;
            string iqty = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Quantity"].ToString();
            string gqty = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Quantity"].ToString();
            string iprice = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Price"].ToString();
            string gprice = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Price"].ToString();
            string itotal = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Inv_Total"].ToString();
            string gtotal = ((DataRowView)DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem)["Grn_Total"].ToString();

            DataGridCell InvQtyCell = GetCell(i, 2);
            DataGridCell GrnQtyCell = GetCell(i, 3);
            DataGridCell InvPriCell = GetCell(i, 4);
            DataGridCell GrnPriCell = GetCell(i, 5);
            DataGridCell InvTotCell = GetCell(i, 6);
            DataGridCell GrnTotCell = GetCell(i, 7);

            string InvoiceCellContentType = InvQtyCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
            string GRNCellContentType = GrnQtyCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
            string InvPriContentType = InvPriCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
            string GrnPriContentType = GrnPriCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
            string InvTotCellType = InvTotCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
            string GrnTotCelType = GrnTotCell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();

            if (iqty == gqty) 
            {
                if (InvoiceCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)InvQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                else if (InvoiceCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)InvQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                if (GRNCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)GrnQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                else if (GRNCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)GrnQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                if (InvoiceCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)InvQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                else if (InvoiceCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)InvQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                if (GRNCellContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)GrnQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                else if (GRNCellContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)GrnQtyCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }

            if (iprice == gprice) 
            {
                if (InvPriContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)InvPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                else if (InvPriContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)InvPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                if (GrnPriContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)GrnPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                else if (GrnPriContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)GrnPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                if (InvPriContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)InvPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                else if (InvPriContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)InvPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                if (GrnPriContentType == "TextBlock") ((TextBlock)GrnPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                else if (GrnPriContentType == "TextBox") ((TextBox)GrnPriCell.Content).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
```

Just in case any one wanted the answer this actually works as long as it is called in

**DgInvoiceLines_CellEditEnding** and **DgInvoiceLines_CurrentCellChanged** only.

I had called it in **DgInvoiceLines_SelectionChanged**  which seems to make it behave strangely.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try Styling your column cells with style that has Triggers on Foreground property?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx